# Thermal conductivity from the mass distribution of an object

Tags: mass, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, thermal-conduction

Thermal conductivity is a property normally related to material. But it is also possible to relate it to objects.

Consider two objects of different shapes made by the same homogeneous material. How can I calculate the effective thermal conductivity of them using their mass distribution and their mass-moment tensors? For example, are the effective thermal conductivity of a cube and a square base cone frustum different?

I believe the mass distribution of an object influences its thermal conductivity. Thus, I expect there is a way do deduce the thermal conductivity of an objects using its volumetric mass distribution.

Could someone help me with it? I looked for textbooks about it, but I didn't find them.

Comment: I don't think you can. The thermal conductivity of a pyramid with a perfect point is zero, but the mass distribution of such a pyramid will not be significantly different from a frustum with a small but finite top area for all I can tell. You can make the same argument for any shape by attaching a needle like structure to it anywhere. Maybe I don't understand what you are asking, though.

Comment: Hi @FlatterMann. Thanks for the comments. Let me give more words about my doubt. 

I expect that two objects made by the same homogeneous material, with the same weight, will conduct heat in different ways if they have different shapes. Am I right? Could you give me some references about your thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I can make the heat conduction through a large chunk of material almost zero by making contact with it in only a very small area, so the idea that somehow an integral quantity describes the total heat conduction can not be valid. You have to solve the equations for heat flow explicitly for the detailed shape, including any cusps.

Comment: Thanks, @FlatterMann! I'm disregarding the contact of my objects with a third one. 

Since you said I am right, do you know any textbook that shows how to calculate the effective thermal conductivity regarding the object's shape? I was reading Ozisik's book (Thermal Conduction), but I didn't find this subject.

Comment: You need to solve the heat equation for steady state, i.e. the time derivative of the temperature field is zero. That boils down to solving the Laplace equation for certain boundary conditions. There is an almost endless amount of mathematical literature about that, both for closed form solutions as well as different kinds of approximations and numerical methods.

Comment: Your way will calculate the effective thermal conductivity, but it doesn't connect the mass distribution with the effective thermal conductivity. For example, if I have iron, is there a way to calculate the effective thermal conductivity of 1kg of iron of a cube and of a square base cone frustum?

Comment: That's my point. The first moments of the mass distribution are not sufficient to calculate heat flow.

Comment: @FlatterMann, do you know any textbook or review articles that deduce the mass moments of the mass distribution? Because all my knowledge on it comes from the article https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.66.031704

Comment: @Caetes Your focus on the mass moments indicates that your question may not be “How do I calculate the conduction heat flux through an arbitrary object?”, as you’ve rejected the answer (solve the heat equation). What are you ultimately trying to do? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi, @Chemomechanics. I believe the mass distribution of an object influences its thermal conductivity. Thus, I expect there is a way to deduce the thermal conductivity of an object using its volumetric mass distribution.

Comment: Your question is confusing because except for the first sentence, it uses "conductivity" incorrectly. As you initially note, "conductivity" is a property of a material. Objects have a "conductance". (This is the same relationship as between electrical resistivity and resistance.) You can calculate the "conductance" of an object from its geometry and the conductivity of the material it is made from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity_and_resistivity) is a material property, independent of the shape of an object.

To incorporate the shape of an arbitrary object, though, we could define a [conductive heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) $U=Q/\Delta T$ corresponding to the conductive heat flux $Q$ (in watts) through the object, given a certain set of boundary conditions and a temperature difference $\Delta T$.

I believe this parameter $U$ is the one you're interested in; is this correct? As noted in the comments, we could refer to $U$ as the **conductance**, analogous to the distinction between the electrical resistivity of a material and the resistance of an object.

If so, consider a thin slice of material with thickness $\Delta x$ and cross-sectional area $A$; [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier%27s_law) tells us that the perpendicular heat transfer magnitude is $Q=kA\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}$, where $k$ is the the material thermal conductivity.

In this way, the conductance $U$ incorporates both the material property and the geometry.

Consider, for example, a solid [1–2–3 block](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/1-2-3_block). If we apply a temperature difference across the two largest surfaces, $U=k\frac{(3\,\mathrm{in})(2\,\mathrm{in})}{1\,\mathrm{in}}$. Across the two smallest surfaces, $k\frac{(2\,\mathrm{in})(1\,\mathrm{in})}{3\,\mathrm{in}}$.

More complex shapes generally require solution of the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) $\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)=0$ subject to the boundary conditions. $Q$ is then found from $Q=-kA\nabla T$ at either of the surfaces where the temperature difference is applied, and $U$ is calculated by normalizing to that particular temperature difference.

**Now to your question**: Is there a path from the mass distribution (or moments of the mass) to the conductive heat transfer coefficient or conductance $U$ defined above? **Yes**: Use the mass distribution to recreate that exact geometry, and then solve the heat equation as described.

Is there otherwise a straightforward path from the moments of the mass to the conductive heat transfer coefficient or conductance? **No.** An infinitesimal gap cutting the object in half would not affect the moments of the mass, but the conductive heat transfer would drop to zero. Thus, there is not a unique heat transfer outcome for a given list of moments of the mass.

Comment: Hi, Chemomechanics! Thank you so much for your answer! I think you're right. And I noticed my ignorance on this subject. Do you have any good reference (book or review article) that shows how to calculate the Thermal Conductance for a circular base cone frustrum?

Comment: The conductance $\pi kr_1r_2/L$ is derived in many locations online, including [here](https://byjus.com/question-answer/the-thermal-conductance-reciprocal-of-the-thermal-resistance-for-axial-flow-of-a-truncated-cone/).

Comment: Could you help me with it? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/801575/71959