# Anisotropic heat flux from anisotropic shape

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

Expanding the discussion in [Thermal conductivity from the mass distribution of an object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797726/71959)

Is it possible to have asymmetric heat flow with linear materials with temperature independent thermal resistivity? For example, in a frustum cone?

To give a numerical example, I did a simulation of a [frustum cone](https://ibb.co/0GmQtKS) surrounded by a homogeneous linear material to guarantees that the area where one applies the inward heat flux is the same for different orientations of the z-direction.

For such a frustum cone with iron outside and glass inside, 293.15 K on one base and 5000 $W/m^2$ on the other, the volume average of Total energy flux magnitude (ht.tefluxMag, $W/m^2$) is 5308.2 $W/m^2$ when the flow of external heat is from bottom to top, and 5402.6 $W/m^2$ when it is from top to bottom. Conclusion: when the nucleus is a bad conductor (glass in this case), the forward direction is from top to bottom.

For a frustum cone with iron inside and glass outside, 293.15 K on one base and 5000 $W/m^2$ on the other, the volume average of Total energy flux magnitude (ht.tefluxMag, $W/m^2$) is 5482.0 $W/m^2$ when the flow of external heat is from bottom to top, and 5330.8 $W/m^2$ when it is from top to bottom.
Conclusion: The forward direction is from bottom to top when the nucleus is a good conductor.

Does someone know why the anisotropic shape produces an anisotropic heat flux? Since the thermal conductance of a frustum cone is the same independently of the heat flux direction, as shown [here](https://byjus.com/question-answer/the-thermal-conductance-reciprocal-of-the-thermal-resistance-for-axial-flow-of-a-truncated-cone/), I expect there is another thermal property beyond the thermal conductance that embodies this phenomenon.

Another perspective of the same question: Is it possible to have an anisotropic convective thermal conduction for such a frustum cone?

Comment: It is not clear if this is a question about the physics of heat flow or a question about the accuracy of finite element software in general and COMSOL Multiphysics in particular. If it is about physics, shouldn't you first ask if asymmetric heat flow is possible with linear materials with temperature independent thermal resistivity. I'll also note that your simulation has two materials which doesn't match the system given in your final link which has a single material surrounded (presumably) by vacuum with zero thermal conductivity.

Comment: Verification of finite element simulations is better suited for Engineering Stack Exchange. The details of how the model was set up, run, and verified can be considered there.

Comment: Hi, @DavidBailey. Thanks for the comments. I added your ideas in the questions.

Comment: Hi, @Chemomechanics. Thanks for the help again! Following David's comments, I changed my question to highlight my doubts about the physics, and not on the simulation.

Comment: If your set boundary condition is 5000 W/m² and you’re measuring 5308 W/m² or something else, your simulation is not functioning correctly. There’s no information here about convergence or evidence that the model’s been validated. This is why I suggested the other site above, for simulation troubleshooting.

Comment: @Chemomechanics, on the other side of the frustum cone has a constant temperature, that can works a source of energy. Thus, this could be the reason that at the surface with constant temperature, the heat flux is greater than 5000 W/m^2